# delphi xe7 upload/download dropbox file using the rest client and show progress

Tags: delphi, upload, dropbox, progress, delphi-xe7

using the xe7 rest client i am able to authenticate and get all kind of information like file list, account info, etc.
how can i now upload and download files with progress indication?
for uploading it will be very useful if there are some examples for small file using **/files_put** (max file size 150MB) and bigger one using **/chunked_upload** from
[Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core)

thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should provide any code that you have problem with. Don't expect that somebody does the job for you.

To give you at least some hint:

You will send the PUT request using IdHTTP according to documentation you have already mentioned. Don't forget to add a header "Authorization" with your login information from the REST client.

```
IdHTTP.Put('https://api-...', FFileStream, FResponseStream);
```

This would block your main thread (UI) so if you want to upload/download and show progress, you have to use a separate thread - so first create a TThread, in the "Work" procedure you will run the upload/download.

Now you have to handle the progress. You can get that in the OnWork event of IdHTTP component. You will pass this status from thread to main thread. Don't forget to synchronize this call correctly - you can use IdNotify for this.

Google will help you with all these basic stuff. Then return and describe any problem.

Comment: sure, i don't expect the full solution! it seems that you also use a separate indy http client component to check the progress. I ask myself why does provide the RESTClient component not the necessary mechanism to implement progress for uploading and downloading...

Comment: You can dig deeper and use IdHTTP inside REST client (request) - YourRESTRequest.Client.HTTPClient.Peer.GetObject as TIdCustomHTTP ... but I don't know if it is possible to use it safely

Comment: i also discovered that the rest client "offer" an http client but is not a fully deployed as indy's one. There are no events that can be used fro e.g. show progress

Comment: REST client uses TIdCustomHTTP (as mentioned above) and it contains OnWork event where you can track progress. Have you tried that?